# Can't install vim in fedora 20

Tags: fedora, vim

When I tried to install VIM in fedora 20, appear this message below

[image: here]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what steps did you make? did you use `yum` or `make` ?

Comment: # yum install vim -y

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose doing:
 `"yum update vim-minimal"`

and then `"yum install vim"`

source:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1066983